# check and uncheck checkboxes calling Ajax with Spring mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to check/ uncheck checkpoints by using Ajax, however it returns 400 bad request.

Can anyone please help!

in the controller:

```
    @RequestMapping("/jsp/check.html") 
    @ResponseBody
    public  ResponseEntity<String> check(@RequestParam Long id){

         String u=SecurityUtils.getUsername();
         User user=userDao.getUser(u).get(0);        
         user.getId();
         Checkpoint cp = userDao.getCheckpoint(id);
         user.getCheckpoints().add(cp);
         userDao.saveUser(user);

        return new ResponseEntity<String>( HttpStatus.OK );

    }


    @RequestMapping("/jsp/uncheck.html") 
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void uncheck(@RequestParam Long id){   

        User user = userDao.getUser(id);
        Checkpoint cp = userDao.getCheckpoint(id);
        user.getCheckpoints().remove(cp);
        userDao.saveUser(user);
    }
```

In display.jsp calling Ajax with jQuery to check and uncheck in this code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#cp").change(function(){ 
      var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

if(checked){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'check.html',
        data: { "id": checked},
        success: function(data){
        }

    });
}
else
{ uncheck();}

});
});

  function uncheck( id )
   {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'uncheck.html',
        data: { "id": id},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @minion     No, there is no errors_

Comment: I am not clear on what you are trying to do here or the problem you are facing. Just saying "does not work" is not helping me here. can you state the exact problem?

Comment: I mean it does not save the data in database. Maybe something wrong in the Ajax call

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `@ModelAttribute` instead of `@RequestParam`.

```
public  ResponseEntity<String> check(@ModelAttribute("id") Long id, HttpSession session){
  //
}
```

Similarly for `uncheck` method also.

Comment: Did not help. I think there is a problem in Ajax call

Comment: what do you receive at the back end?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Ajax and do not know how to call backend

Comment: to call back end you are using AJAX....:):)    can you check your network tab,what request is going forward?

Comment: when check the chekbox, the status is 400 bad request.